# Is it possible to copy my System Preferences to another Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, system-preferences

For instance, I want to copy my Expose settings to another mac, as well as power management, appearance, and a couple of other things.  Is this possible?  If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find most system preferences in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`, and user
preferences in `~/Library/Preferences/`. For OS X most settings files will start with `com.apple`. To view the contents of such `.plist` files, you need Property List Editor (included in the Apple Developer Tools), or use `plutil` to convert it.

The Energy Saver settings are in `com.apple.PowerManagement.plist`. I guess Exposé might be included in the Dock preferences, `com.apple.dock.plist`. Its key bindings are in `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`.

I'm not sure if copying the whole files is a good idea; surely you first need to peek into them to see what else is configured.

(I think `com.apple.systempreferences.plist` mainly holds the preferences of the System Preferences itself.)

Comment: Thanks, yeah these worked but you need to be very careful.  I made backups before I did anything and ran into a lot of trouble, so the backups helped.

Comment: @GiH, I kind of expected someone to mention Migration Assistant (in Applications, Utilities). But as you already accepted this answer, I decided to see for myself. No cigar: running it on two Macs gives you the option to (optionally) transfer Accounts, and/or files, and/or [the preferences for](http://macs.about.com/od/leopard105/ss/migratevol_4.htm) Network Settings, Time Zone, and Sharing Settings. Not what you asked for.

Comment: thanks for following up!  I actually had already attempted migration assistant, should have mentioned that, but like you said it wouldn't do what I was asking for.  Manually moving those files over worked perfectly, I just suggest backing up first and ONLY moving over the files you actually need and again, being careful.  Always good to inspect the files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have **not** tried this, but it should *theoretically* be possible to copy the contents of `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/` from one MacOS installation to another to copy over different system preferences.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't save the preferences, only copied the pane.